# gparted partition master boot record corrupt

Tags: partition, gparted

I was trying to Linux  Mint from live-usb and made a stupid mistake.
I created master boot record and my HDD partition become unallocated.
After rebooting from live OS, I'm unable to get to boot menu.

[image]

Is there any way to recover all my data? Right now I can only boot to live-usb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to avoid messing up, you should backup an entire image of the disk (provided you have a bigger disk to store it). For this, several solutions are proposed [on this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later), last time i did it, I used `dd`. Once you are sure you can restore the image in case of problem, you can use `testdisk` to redetect the partition table and fix it.

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/299594/recovery-via-fsck) for instance provides a solution.